# How to model energy production capacity

Tags: modeling, marketing

I am doing market research for wind energy production capacity (in megawatt) in an African country. I have data about the wind energy production capacity over the years. It looks like the following :

[image]

Each year, new wind farms are constructed, which add more megawatts to the existing wind energy production capacity.

I am thinking of modeling the number of added megawatts each year as a random variable in order to be able to do some projections. The statistical model that seems to me to best fit here is Poisson.

My question is: is Poisson the best model to consider in this situation or are there any more specific models for the special case I am working on?

Answer (score 1):

Energy production is not discrete. You can have half a megawatt of increment, for instance.

Since the model is that you have a bunch of farms contributing a bunch of MWs of energy, it seems like the **Erlang distribution** would be a natural fit. Depending on what your software setup is, you may prefer a **Gamma distribution** instead, of which Erlang is a special case.

In particular, if you don't know how many farms you have and/or what are their capacities, a hierarchical Gamma->Gamma model could handle that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that Poisson distribution family is discrete and is not the most precise model for my random variable. As to Erlang distribution, correct me if I am wrong, but I think that it is more known for modeling waiting *time* until kth arrival in a Poisson process. How exactly would be it used to model energy production capacity?

Comment: What it's usually used for is irrelevant, what matters is what it *is*. It's a distribution of the sum of N variables with a real-valued mean M each (so is Gamma, the only difference is that N has to be an integer for Erlang and a real for Gamma). Time lag is positive real-valued and has a bunch of N discrete producers in a Poisson process, so it's used there, because it fits the definition; so does real-valued number of MWs of energy from N farms.